# Voltage Reference Question

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, voltage-reference, ota

I'm new to regulators and references and I'm trying to update this old circuit that uses an op-amp as a 2.5V voltage reference. The new circuit will possibly use LM4040, but I'm not sure if it needs to be isolated from the LM13700's inputs or if it can be used as is. Anybody have experience with this kind of set up?
[image: OLD]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3848/32695603842_0360f1ec9a.jpg))</sub>

[image: NEW]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2316/32725432091_353df711d3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: If you're new to regulators, why aren't you using a simple regulator chip?

Comment: Precision is important, current requirement is low

Comment: Then get a voltage reference IC. Those are precision, where current requirement is low.

Comment: not familiar with many series references. what's wrong with using a shunt reference?

Comment: nothing wrong, just that there are chips that save the hassle by having all in one.

Comment: Design for manufacturing would require cost to be considered.  That  makes the 4040 a much better choice than say a Ref02 if it's all that is needed.

Comment: Wow -- that's an expensive way to go, but at least the LM4040 gets rid of problems with resistor tolerance.  Be sure you really understand your precision requirements, and make sure a more conventional approach won't meet them, before carving this in stone.

Comment: Is 0.05% accuracy w/ a 10ppm/° Temp coeff good enough??  (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1634ff.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I've done nearly that exact same thing a number of times and it worked fine for me.  I assume V+ is not too high to exceed the shunt current limit.

Comment: Vcc is 12V. I will take a look